# C++ doesn't receive data with ReadFile/WriteFile when I'm trying to talk to a TTI device

Tags: c++, serial-port

I come to you because I have some problems when I trying to write a driver supporting the QL355P from TTI. I already wrote the driver in VB6, but now, I am trying to write it in C++. I use the ReadFile/WriteFile function to communicate with the interface. The problem is when I send the identification command (*IDN?) and the endchar (.), I have no response (I have Statut_timeout).

My code is:

```
DCB l_dcb;
BOOL l_Success;
 COMMTIMEOUTS l_TimeOuts;
 const char *command = "*IDN?.";
 // open an access to serial port
 m_ComPort = CreateFile(L"COM2",
  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
  0,    // comm devices must be opened w/exclusive-access
  NULL, // no security attrs
  OPEN_EXISTING, // comm devices must use OPEN_EXISTING
  0,    // not overlapped I/O
  NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
  );

 // get the current configuration
 l_Success = GetCommState(m_ComPort, &l_dcb);

 // fill in the DCB with configuation:
// baud=19200, 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit
l_dcb.BaudRate = 19200;
l_dcb.ByteSize = 8;
l_dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
l_dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

// configure the port
l_Success = SetCommState(m_ComPort, &l_dcb);

// get the current time-outs configuration
l_Success = GetCommTimeouts(m_ComPort, &l_TimeOuts);

 // change the time-outs
l_TimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
l_TimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=50;
l_TimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=1000;

// sets the time-outs configuration
l_Success = SetCommTimeouts(m_ComPort, &l_TimeOuts);

// first purge the input buffer
PurgeComm(m_ComPort,PURGE_RXCLEAR);

// send the command
DWORD l_NumBytesTransfered=0;
DWORD l_NumBytesToTransfer=strlen(command);
l_Success = WriteFile(m_ComPort,command,l_NumBytesToTransfer,&l_NumBytesTransfered,NULL);

//Try to read
char l_Char='*';
int i=0;
char l_Pointer[100];
while(l_Char !=0x0a && i<100)
{
    l_Success = ReadFile(m_ComPort,&l_Char,1,&l_NumBytesTransfered,NULL);

    l_Pointer[i] = l_Char;
    i++;
}
CloseHandle(m_ComPort); //close the handle
```

Answer (score 0):

ReadFile can return 0 in case of a timeout, or various possible errors. Your code snippet ignores that possibility and puts garbage into the input array even when ReadFile fails.